# Get html attribute? selenium / bs4

Tags: python, selenium

How do I get the value of status= on an twitch page using bs4 or selenium ?

[Example of someone offline](https://www.twitch.tv/mizkif)

How it shows in the html source:

```
<a class="ScHalo-sc-1l14b0i-0 dcbwCs tw-halo" size="72" status="offline" href="/mizkif">........</a>
```

code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

op = Options()
op.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\bestg\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\bor")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/mizkif')
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
#HOW DO GET VALUE OF "STATUS=" in soup?
#unrelated: (used to focus offline streams)
#click the avatar 
stream = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//a[@status='offline']")))
stream.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get_attribute(name)` function in Selenium

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/the/X/path")
attribute = element.get_attribute('status')
```

PS: driver.find_element with that syntax works with Selenium 4